# How to prune a citrus tree?

Tags: trees, pruning, citrus

I'm interested how to prune correctly or the best way a citrus tree.
I can give an example of an indoor orange tree. Would it be ok to trim the left branch until the bottom leaf you can see in the image and the other branches by one third? I live in the temperate climate. In the winter I've kept the tree in a cool room and in the summer outside. [image: Orange tree]

Answer (score 3):

What is it that you would like to achieve with pruning? Is it esthetic, or to get your tree to grow taller? Or fuller? Does this plant carry any fruit yet, or is it still too young?

Anyways, for esthetic reasons I would prune the left branch completely. To the stem of the plant. If you want the plant to become larger and fuller (in order to develop fruits?), then I would suggest to not prune it yet, but put it in a larger container.

Furthermore, the time of pruning is also important, especially when your plant develops fruits already. If you live in the Northern hemisphere, probably the best time to prune should be early spring (Feb-Apr).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to make the tree more compact as right now it is overspreaded and taking up much space. So fuller and not too high would be the best. Right now is not fruiting, but sprouting new leafs. It was full of flowers from February till July and lost all its fruit beginnings around August. The tree has almost 2 years. In the winter I kept it in a cool but sunny room. Right now it is still outside as the lowering temperatures are still between 8 and 20 Celsius grades.

Comment: To make the plant more compact, I would recommend to remove the whole left branch and let the rest of the plant be until next spring.